# Gcloud build trigger environment variable substitution in app.yaml for appEngine

Tags: triggers, yaml, gcloud, app.yaml

I am trying to substitue variable in app.yaml with a cloud build trigger.

I Added substitution variable in build trigger.

Add environment variables to app.yaml in a way they can be easily substituted with build trigger variables. Like this:

```
env_variables:
 SECRET_KEY: %SECRET_KEY%
```

Add a step in cloudbuild.yaml to substitute all %XXX% variables inside app.yaml with their values from build trigger.

```
    steps:
    - name: node:10.15.1
       entrypoint: npm
       args: ["install"]
    - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
       entrypoint: bash
       args:
         - '-c'
         - |
           sed -i 's/%SESSION_SECRET%/'${_SESSION_SECRET}'/g' app.yaml
    timeout: "1600s"
```

The problem is that Gcloud Build throw an exception :

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
bash: _L/g: No such file or directory
```

Why ? How can I make a substitution of my app.yaml ?

I have a app.yaml to the root of the project at the same level of the cloudbuild.yaml

**UPDATED**

I am trying to build and debug gcloud locally with this command:

```
sudo cloud-build-local --config=cloudbuild.yaml --write-workspace=../workspace --dryrun=false --substitutions=_SESSION_SECRET=test --push .
```

When I take a look into the app.yaml file, the substitution worked as expected and there is no exception at all.

What is the difference with the gcloud build environment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I finally decided to use github action instead of google cloud triggers.

Since Google cloud triggers aren't able to find its own app.yaml and manage the freaking environment variable by itself.

**Here is how to do it:**

**My environment :**
App engine,
standard (not flex),
Nodejs Express application,
a PostgreSQL CloudSql

**First the setup :**

```
1. Create a new Google Cloud Project (or select an existing project).

2. Initialize your App Engine app with your project.

[Create a Google Cloud service account][sa] or select an existing one.

3. Add the the following Cloud IAM roles to your service account:

    App Engine Admin - allows for the creation of new App Engine apps

    Service Account User - required to deploy to App Engine as service account

    Storage Admin - allows upload of source code

    Cloud Build Editor - allows building of source code

[Download a JSON service account key][create-key] for the service account.

4. Add the following [secrets to your repository's secrets][gh-secret]:

    GCP_PROJECT: Google Cloud project ID

    GCP_SA_KEY: the downloaded service account key
```

**The app.yaml**

```
runtime: nodejs14
env: standard
env_variables:
  SESSION_SECRET: $SESSION_SECRET
beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: SQL_INSTANCE
```

**Then the github action**

```
name: Build and Deploy to GKE

on: push

env:
  PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.GKE_PROJECT }}
  DATABASE_URL: ${{ secrets.DATABASE_URL}}
jobs:
  setup-build-publish-deploy:
    name: Setup, Build, Publish, and Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

steps:
 - uses: actions/checkout@v2
 - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
   with:
    node-version: '12'
 - run: npm install
 - uses: actions/checkout@v1
 - uses: ikuanyshbekov/app-yaml-env-compiler@v1.0
   env:
    SESSION_SECRET: ${{ secrets.SESSION_SECRET }}  
 - shell: bash
   run: |
        sed -i 's/SQL_INSTANCE/'${{secrets.DATABASE_URL}}'/g' app.yaml
 - uses: actions-hub/gcloud@master
   env:
    PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.GKE_PROJECT }}
    APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: ${{ secrets.GCLOUD_AUTH }}
    CLOUDSDK_CORE_DISABLE_PROMPTS: 1
   with:
    args: app deploy app.yaml
```

To add secrets into git hub action you must go to : Settings/secrets

Take note that I could handle all the substitution with the bash script. So I would not depend on the github project "ikuanyshbekov/app-yaml-env-compiler@v1.0"

It's a shame that GAE doesn't offer an easiest way to handle environment variable for the app.yaml. I don't want to use KMS since I need to update the beta-settings/cloud sql instance.. I really needed to substitute everything into the app.yaml.

This way I can make a specific action for the right environment and manage the secrets.

Answer (score 0):

The entrypoint should be an executable, use `/bin/bash` or `/bin/sh`.

How to inspect inside the image (in general):

```sh
$ docker pull gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from cloud-builders/gcloud
...
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                     TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED             SIZE
gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud   latest    8499764c4ef6   About an hour ago   4.01GB
$ docker run -ti --entrypoint '/bin/bash' 8499764c4ef6
root@60354dfb588a:/#
```

You can test your commands from there to test without having to sending it to Cloud Build each time.

Comment: I updated my question with your suggestion. See the results of my test. Thanks!

Comment: It is not clear to me what are you asking, Cloud Build is a very generic tool for
https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/build-config

Comment: I am trying to get my substitution to work on gcloud build with the cloudbuild.yaml. when i debug locally, I don't get the exception "no such file or directory"

Comment: You are clearly on an anti-pattern here. You can set environment variables with both app.yaml and with cloudbuild.yaml. Requiring a substitution in build time with `sed` is the anti-pattern.

Comment: Ok I will try to set the substitution directly in the ENV_VAR: from app.yaml. It would be so simple if it worked like that.